# Prevent $resource.$save() from altering resource data AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-resource

In the example below, I do some transformation with the retrieved resource from an API.

```
var resource = $resource('http://example.com/resource/:id');

$scope.record = resource.get({id: 123});

$scope.record.$promise.then(function(response) {
   // do some transformations
   response.date = moment(response.date, "YYYY-MM-dd").format("dd MM YYYY");
});
```

In the same way, I do transformation of the data before it gets saved.

```
var record.$save();
```

The POST data I submitted is returned back by the API. That return value becomes the new value of the Resource object.

However, it's not the format I use when displaying as demonstrated with the GET.

Is there a way to prevent $save() from replacing the value of the Resource?

Answer (score 0):

There is an open issue to have an option added to ngResource to disable this behavior ([#8370](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/8370)).

In the meantime, use the `transformResponse` option in your `save` action definition:

```
app.factory('Things', ['$resource', function($resource) {
    var transform = function(data, headersGetter) {
        data.date = moment(response.date, "YYYY-MM-dd").format("dd MM YYYY");
        return data;
    };

    return $resource('/thing/:id', {}, {
        'get': {
            'transformResponse': transform
        },
        'save': {
            'transformResponse': transform
        }
    });
}]);
```

See: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource

Comment: save() is a service method, $save() is an instance method, i.e. Things.save(thing) vs thing.$save().

Comment: There were bugs in the original example posted, that's why it didn't work. Will upvote after someone reviews my edit.